# Azure SPN Password end date creation in Terraform in hours

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm using terraform to create a service principal in Azure and also its password, however, I want to limit the password end in hours and in days. Please, how can I achieve this in terraform. my current code is below

```
resource "azuread_service_principal_password" "test" {
  service_principal_id       = azuread_service_principal.test.id
  value                      = "jsjjjja"
  end_date                   = 2021-07-23T12:00:00Z
  }
```

How do I limit it to the current day and for a number of hours?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Terraform bydefault declares the startdate as per the UTC(now) criteria, you can just mention `end_date_relative  =  "2h"` to limit it to 2hrs from the creation time or you can can even set to days as well in terms of hours for example 10 days will be 240h.

So code will be as below:

```
resource  "azuread_service_principal_password"  "example" { 
service_principal_id  =  azuread_service_principal.example.object_id 
value  =  "Example12345" 
end_date_relative  =  "2h"  #expiry for current date in 2 hrs 
}
```

Output can be seen in terraform.tfstate file:

[image]

**Reference:**

[Azure_Service_Principal_Password_terraform-registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/service_principal_password)